# Gradient Computation on GPU

Tags: python, c++, numpy

For the last 2 days i have been trying to actually compute the gradients of a pictures stack in python.

Numpy.gradient() gives me values but they are not good enough for my Edge detection, so i kinda wrote my own kernel to multiply on each value in the Array with Gray values (lets call it stack).

So numpy.gradients() is really fast but not good enough, my gradient computation takes a lot of time (around 45 minutes). Implementing the same in C++ with the help of OpenCV and CV Matrices made everything much faster (around 3 minutes) but i fail to build a wrapper between python and c++.

Is there a way to take an numpy float32 array of shape NxMxK and somehow calculate the gradient in direction x,y,z , on the GPU? I tried cudamat but there are only basic matrix operations and tensorflow or pytorch seem to be to complicated :(

Comment: If you have cuda I recommend taking a look at https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python. That way you don't have to write a wrapper to C/C++

Comment: But isn‘t the CUDA Part the exact Same as writing c Code ?